# Appending new value to existing (reverse) dictionary in other for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I created a dictionary with a for loop.

Now i want to add the index values of the words in a list to this dictionary.

So the value of num in enumerate(olist) has to be added to the corresponding word in the dictionary.

Code:

```
def reverse_dict(input):
    output = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for key, val in input.items():
        for item in val:
            output[item].append(key)

    return output


def main():
    olist = []
    worddict = {} 

    for line in sys.stdin:
        i,u,t,w = line.split('\t')
        splitword = (w.split())
        olist.extend(splitword)
        worddict[i] = splitword




    for num,name in enumerate(olist):
        #splitword.extend([num])
        #worddict[i].extend([num])
        print("{} [{}]".format(name.strip(), num))

    output = reverse_dict(worddict)
    print(output)
```

Current output1:

```
RT [0]
@AfshinEllian1 [1]
: [2]
Kennelijk [3]
vinden [4]
ze [5]
daar [6]
etc..
```

Current output2 :

```
{'RT': ['1035421930541772800', '1035421931321864192'], '@AfshinEllian1': ['1035421930541772800'], ':': ['1035421930541772800', '1035421931321864192'], 'Kennelijk': ['1035421930541772800'], 'vinden': ['1035421930541772800'], 'ze': ['1035421930541772800'], 'daar': ['1035421930541772800'], 'aan': ['1035421930541772800'], 'die': ['1035421930541772800'], 'gezellige': ['1035421930541772800'], 'tafel': ['1035421930541772800'], 'normaal': ['1035421930541772800'], 'dat': ['1035421930541772800'], 'steltje': ['1035421930541772800'], 'barbaren': ['1035421930541772800'], 'onze': ['1035421930541772800'], 'grondwettelijke': ['1035421930541772800'], 'rechten': ['1035421930541772800'], 'bedreigen': ['1035421930541772800'], '.': ['1035421930541772800'], 'Zouden': ['1035421930541772800'], 'we': ['1035421930541772800'], 'ook': ['1035421930541772800']
```

Expected output :

```
{'RT': ['1035421930541772800', '1035421931321864192', '0'], 
'@AfshinEllian1': ['1035421930541772800', '1']
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by index value? The count of values? Or their position in the original text?

Comment: Python3, I mean their position in the original text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given the list and the reverse dictionary, you want to append the index of each item to the corresponding entry in the dictionary. Maybe this will do it:

```
d = reverse_dict(worddict)

for num, name in enumerate(olist):
    d[name].append(num)
```

Now the dictionary `d` would be your expected dictionary.

Comment: I agree, but this would result in a list where the `id` like values and the positions are mixed... Maybe a tuple for each would be preferable?

Comment: True, I don't know the context of the question to say why Stefan wanted to do it this way.